# Chrome Permissions: System.display

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to get display information in my chrome extension. I was very successful to get it in manifest version 2 with "system.display" permission.
The API I used,

```
chrome.system.display.getinfo((info)=>{
      console.log(info);
    }
);
```

I am trying the same in manifest version 3, but it's giving me the error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
```

My manifest file,

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
},
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "history", "storage", "system.display"]
```

Please help me to find out where I am making mistake.

One more thing, I read something like **availability: foreground only,** in a document of [chrome.system.display](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/system_display/) API. If someone can explain what that exactly means then it'll be great knowledge you share with me.

Thanks

Comment: It means the currently this API can be used only in a visible page of your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm My extension has no page. it's work like on click extension.

Comment: To reiterate, your options are: 1) use a page, 2) keep MV2 and wait for this bug to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm for the quick replies and guiding me, Just help me to resolve one more doubt, Is this bug in the chrome extension. what exactly the issue is ..?

Comment: It's not implemented for service workers yet.

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, Thank you so much for providing this much information. Can you please also help me to know how long it can take to resolve this problem/bug.

Comment: I don't know. I guess it may be implemented by the end of the year.

Comment: 2022 and this is still not available :)